# CoreData and tableview

Tags: swift, core-data

How can a tableview (in another view controller) read this data from first view controller?

Should I put this into array or something? This is code for retrieving saved data, I already managed to save data.

```
do {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
    let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    if results.count > 0 {
        for item in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
            let name = item.valueForKey("username")
            let password = item.valueForKey("passwords")
            print(name!, password!)
            array.append (name, password) // this do not work, can't put that in array so tableview can read array in another vc.
        }
    }
}
```

When I put name and password objects in array it says:

> Cannot convert any object to array string

How can I retrieve core data to array so tableview can read from array, or should it read from coredata directly?

Comment: What is the type declaration for `array`? As for passing data to another table view controller, you could just pass the managed object context and let it run its own fetch request. you could even pass it a configured fetch request that it could add to a fetched results controller that acts as the date source for your table view. You could pass it an array of ManagedObjectIDs that the tableview could turn into objects from it's own managed object context.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that there are different solutions you could use that all depend on the context of what you are trying to do. Core Data is complex because it supports all these different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data from VC A to VC B, you should use segue method and the display data in the tableView.
Segue method

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: nil)
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! AlreadyStartViewController
        destination.variable = variable /*and other*/
    }
}
```

And then display data in the tableView
If you want to ask me about code - ask